# Conditions on $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ to ensure a finite number of crossings

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable except at a finite number of points. Can you give me some examples of additional hypotheses that would guarantee that

$$\text{For any $c\in \mathbb{R},\,f$ crosses $c$ a finite number of times. } \tag{1}$$

I think the notion of a "crossing" is sufficiently clear, but if it is not, perhaps we can discuss that also.

To start at the simplest, $f$ being a piecewise polynomial is sufficient.

An example of one that doesn't work is supposing $f$ analytic except at its points of non-differentiability. This isn't sufficient, since $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}:x\mapsto \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ and $0\mapsto 0$ is a counter-example.

Comment: Finite variation maybe?

Comment: It i sof course sufficient to study the case that $f$ is differentiable on $(a,b)$. And one sifficient condition is of course that $(f')^{-1}(\{0\})$ is finite.

Comment: @Bunder Isn't $e^{-1/x^2}\sin(1/x)$, $0\mapsto 0$ on $[-1,1]$ of finite variation?

Comment: @EricAuld Is derivable, so I guess that my guess was not good :).

Answer (score 3):

The example that doesn't work can be turned into one that does. Let $a=x_0,x_1,\dots,x_n=b$ be a partition of interval $[a,b]$ such that $f$ is differentiable on each $(x_{i-1},x_i)$. The following is a sufficient condition for the finiteness of crossings:

*For $i=1,\dots,n$, $f$ extends as a real-analytic function to an open interval containing $[x_{i-1},x_i]$.*

The proof is easy: having an accumulation point of $\{f=c\}$ within an interval of analyticity forces the function to be constant on that interval.

Another condition, more general but perhaps more difficult to verify, is

*There is an integer $m$ such that the derivative $f^{(m)}$ changes sign finitely many times.*

Indeed, a repeated application of Rolle's theorem yields the finiteness of crossings.